# Promedio de cada auto MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MySQL

```
create table alquilan (
    matricula varchar(20) not null,
    id_usuario numeric not null,
    n_tarjeta varchar(50) not null,
    codigo_seguridad varchar(10) not null,
    precio numeric not null,
    check_in date not null,
    check_out date not null,
    comentario varchar(200) not null,
    puntaje numeric not null,
    foreign key (id_usuario) references usuarios(id_usuario),
    foreign key (matricula) references vehiculos(matricula)
);
```

Entonces, cada vez que se alquile un auto, una nueva celda será creada con los datos de este, ahora bien, teniendo yo esto, ¿como puedo calcular el promedio del puntaje de CADA auto?

Puedo obtener el promedio de puntaje TOTAL con `select avg(puntaje) from alquilan`, pero este sería de todos los autos.

Necesitaría el de cada uno, por ejemplo, si el auto con matricula `AAA-111` se alquilo 3 veces, y obtuvo en esos 3 alquileres  `3`, `4` y `7` de puntaje necesitaría obtener: `3 + 4 + 7 /`

Comment: La cantidad y el promedio por matricula, lo podes obtener con un group by matricula , pero que son esos puntajes (3,4 y 7) ?

Comment: @PatrickArguello es un campo de la tabla, eso lo hace con el avg que tiene, solo le faltaba el group by

Comment: @Sr1871 gracias por tu ayuda en localizar el campo puntaje.

Comment: *Entonces, cada vez que se alquile un auto, una nueva celda será creada con los datos de este* ¿o sea, que en la misma tabla creas una **celda** cada vez que alquilan ese auto? ¿O quisiste decir que se crea una nueva **fila** por cada alquiler?

Answer (score 1):

Solo le esta faltado el agrupamiento a tu sentencia, quedaria de esta forma:

```
select matricula, avg(puntaje) from alquilan 
  group by matricula;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver tu problema solo debes agregar la sentencia `GROUP BY` a tu consulta. El objetivo de `GROUP BY` es darle una columna y se formaran grupos dependiendo de los diversos valores que existan en esa columna.

Por ejemplo:

```
Placas | Puntaje
-----------------
AAA-123| 4
BBB-987| 5
AAA-123| 8
```

Si ejecutas la siguiente sentencia, se formaran dos grupos, uno para la placa `AAA-123` y otro para la placa `BBB-987`, entonces cuando tu ejecutas la función `AVG(puntaje)` estás sacando el promedio de los puntajes de cada grupo.

```sql
SELECT placas, AVG(puntaje)
FROM alquilan
GROUP BY placas
```

Dando por resultado lo siguiente:

```
PLACAS | AVG(puntaje)
---------------------
AAA-123| 6
BBB-987| 5
```